# has_ancestry/ assigning hierarchy to existing table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a database that is imported from a CSV file and I would like to assign hierarchy  based on the assembly level below. 
not sure which approach to take. 
I can write if statements but it will be very long. 
sorry I am new to this, and I don't know where to begin. any help is much appreciated.

```
assembly_level         assembly_tree           description      uniq_id
0                      zero level               "zero level"    d9s64
1                       level one assembly      "level one"     c9633
2                        level two assembly     "level two"     11197
3                         level three assembly  "level three"   e271f
4                          level four assembly  "level four"    552da
4                          level four assembly  "level four"    4568a
3                         level three assembly  "level three"   b72bd
```

edit

who can I assign assembly_level to Parent_id during import?

`@item = Item.new(:assembly_level=> params[:parent_id])`

Comment: if you are using ancestry gem, just create instance with parent_id as attribute. you can find your parent by `assembly_level`.

Comment: you mean, 
   
`@item = Item.new()`
`@item.parent_id=params[:assembly_level] `
What m I missing?